# Can't publish module from android studio to jitpack

Tags: android, jitpack

I am trying to publish an android app module to https://jitpack.io/ but I'm getting the following error:

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' (type 'ProcessApplicationManifest').
  - In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest' property 'mainManifest' specifies file '/home/jitpack/build/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' which doesn't exist.
```

So far I have found that the task `app:generateDebugBuildConfig` is not present in the executed task list.

My project location https://github.com/ikramuldu/ahmadullah
Trying to publish `notifier` module.

Full stacktrace https://jitpack.io/com/github/ikramuldu/ahmadullah/1.7/build.log

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
java version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.7+8-LTS-224, mixed mode, sharing)
Getting tasks: ./gradlew tasks --all
Tasks: publishToMavenLocal,
Running: ./gradlew clean -Pgroup=com.github.ikramuldu -Pversion=1.7 -xtest -xlint assemble publishToMavenLocal
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 v.33.0.1".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 v.33.0.1" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/33.0.1
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 v.33.0.1" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 v.33.0.1" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 33 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 33 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 33 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-33
"Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision 3)" finished.
> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :notifier:clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :notifier:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :notifier:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :notifier:generateDebugResValues
> Task :notifier:generateDebugResources
> Task :notifier:writeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :notifier:packageDebugResources
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:packageDebugResources
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :notifier:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :notifier:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :notifier:compileDebugLibraryResources
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
19 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 3 up-to-date
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugMainManifest' (type 'ProcessApplicationManifest').
  - In plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check' type 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest' property 'mainManifest' specifies file '/home/jitpack/build/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml' which doesn't exist.
    
    Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Make sure the file exists before the task is called.
      2. Make sure that the task which produces the file is declared as an input.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#input_file_does_not_exist for more details about this problem.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Publication: com.github.ikramuldu:ahmadullah:1.7
Build tool exit code: 0
Looking for artifacts...
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
Looking for pom.xml in build directory and ~/.m2
Found artifact: com.github.ikramuldu:ahmadullah:1.7
2023-08-24T11:30:08.184731891Z
Exit code: 0

⚠️ ERROR: No build artifacts found
Expected artifacts in: $HOME/.m2/repository/com/github/ikramuldu/ahmadullah/1.7
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I've made the same mistake as you.

Comment: Nope @onita not yet.